# Consecutive `System.loadLibrary` returns `UnsatisfiedLinkError`

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I currently have two libraries I'm trying to load via JNI - `libA.so` and `libB.so`. Documentation from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) leads me to believe that I can simply do:

```
System.loadLibrary("A");
System.loadLibrary("B");
```

and then compile and run like so:

```
java -Djava.library.path="/path/to/libs" -jar myjarfile.jar
```

However, doing this only appears to load the first library as the second one throws the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /path/to/libs/libB.so: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Upon verifying that both libraries were in the path specified by `java.library.path`, I swapped the statements i.e.:

```
System.loadLibrary("B");
System.loadLibrary("A");
```

and found that the issue is now with loading library `A`:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /path/to/libs/libA.so: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

leading me to believe that I'm unable to make consecutive `loadLibrary` calls for whatever reason. Executing `java -XshowSettings:properties` also confirms that I have correctly set `java.library.path` to the location of the libraries.

I've attempted to use `System.load()` instead:

```
System.load("/path/to/libs/libA.so");
System.load("/path/to/libs/libB.so");
```

in addition to setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`but no luck - this gives me the same issue where the first library gets loaded but the second library throws `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`

I'm banging my head against the wall - anyone have any ideas?

(note: I don't think it's relevant, but I'm running my code in a docker container built on the ubuntu image)

Comment: This link provides the list of possible way to address the issue -https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/02/22/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file/. Also this would help - https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1549365534-The-difference-between-System-load-and-System-loadLibrary-in-Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error fully, you will notice that in both cases it refers to *libgomp* being missing. It is likely that your shared objects (either of them) depend on it.

Make sure libgomp was properly installed on your platform and try again. Pretty sure it would solve the problem.

Comment: Try this - `sudo apt-get install libgomp1` , If you're on Ubuntu 14.04+, this should fix it. Just did a quick search and apparently libgomp1 is not installed by default anymore on Ubuntu 14.04 or later

Comment: @tomtzook @Ramesh you're both right! It should've been a red flag but, for the same reason mentioned by @ramesh, I thought it was installed by default as I had been able to compile it on another ubuntu machine. However, I'm still puzzled as to why this error is only thrown on the second `loadLibrary` as opposed to both if both depend on `libgomp`?

Comment: Does the stacktrace show that it’s only from the second call each time? It should be thrown depending on the library you load, so it doesn’t actually make sense. Can you check the stacktraces to make sure?